# How do I make a clickable image in Clojure with Hiccup

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, hiccup

Right now I have a logo and then a link to the homepage. I want to combine them so that someone can click the logo and be directed to the homepage. I can't figure out how to do this with Hiccup.

```
    [:div.navbar-brand
         [:img {:src "/img/logo.png"
                :width 70
                :height 50}]
         
         [:a.navbar-item
          {:href "/"
           :style {:font-weight "bold"}}
          "Home"]
```

I am trying to do something like

```
    [:a.navbar-item
          {:href "/"}
           {:img {:src "/img/logo.png"
                  :width 70
                  :height 50}}]
```

But it's not working. What do I do?

Comment: In 2nd example, does changing the { } enclosures to [ ] work for img?Changing `{:img {:src "/img/logo.png" :width 70 :height 50}}]` to `[:img {:src "/img/logo.png" :width 70 :height 50}]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Img` is element inside `a`, not attribute of `a`, so use square brackets:

```
[:a.navbar-item
           {:href "/"}
           [:img {:src "/img/logo.png"
                  :width 70
                  :height 50}]]
```